# Wordpress installation directory and custom homepage

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have wordpress for CMS contents. Where my homepage will be a standalone application, suppose I want to build a single page application using backbone, how i can install/configure with wordpress?

Comment: Install wodpress in the root of your directory and just make a custom homepage. Why do you want a homepage outside wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Better put your wordpress in a subdirectory (blog or whatever name). Otherwise you might end up with `htaccess` problems. It is possible to do it in the same directory though. You can even just make your custom front page as part of the wordpress theme. But thats up to you.

Comment: i have to exclude the homepage because I want it to be standalone. If i install wp in mydomain.com/blog, can my blog post be mydomain.com/category/post-1 ?

Comment: With some customization yes.

Answer (score 0):

Just install wordpress as you normally would and create your own theme with a single page. If you check out the documentation on theme development you will have it up and running within an hour.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development